# Create a SQL query that merges rows

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table that stores the dates when an order was opened and closed. It's similar to this:

| id | orderID | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | opened | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | closed | 2020-01-05 |
| 3 | 2 | opened | 2020-01-02 |

I need an SQL query that returns the following result:

| orderId | openedDate | closedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | NULL |

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT
orderId,
CASE WHEN status = 'opened' THEN date END AS openedDate,
CASE WHEN status = 'closed' THEN date END AS closedDate

FROM
orders

GROUP BY
orderId;
```

But I'm not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get a syntax error, because the `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by`.  Use aggregation:

```
SELECT orderId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'opened' THEN date END) AS openedDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' THEN date END) AS closedDate
FROM orders
GROUP BY orderId;
```